# How do I plot collections of patches of polygons with each collection of patches has a different color with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon

I have been trying to plot a bunch of polygons, which has been easy. But now I am trying to color code each polygon based on a certain parameter. First I grouped them in a dictionary under the parameter and then from the coordinates of each polygon made a polygon and appended it to a patch which then I put into a collection. Repeating for each parameter and set of polygons in that parameter.

So far I have only been able to get the polygons to be all different colors or all the same color.

I also tried using collection.set_color(color), with both an individual color and a list of colors, but had the same problem.

```
dictionary = dictionary = {'a': [[[-118.32329238389097, 33.9339393168853], [-118.32346875508487, 33.93393898329083], [-118.32347696574647, 33.93393841351066], [-118.32348494952662, 33.93393671429208], [-118.32349248408008, 33.93393393259884], [-118.32349935955001, 33.93393014799156], [-118.32350538676975, 33.93392546230189], [-118.32351039523573, 33.93392000822456], [-118.32351424748364, 33.933913937257486], [-118.32351683702177, 33.93390741798959], [-118.3235180903646, 33.933900629226144], [-118.32351820943661, 33.93387166681243], [-118.32351458920945, 33.93383104642852], [-118.32350380421424, 33.93379131762032], [-118.32348609066355, 33.93375335562479], [-118.32346183707868, 33.9337179940535], [-118.32341498168088, 33.93366417935979], [-118.32329244451628, 33.933664204300676], [-118.32329238389097, 33.9339393168853]], [[-118.32324559387409, 33.93226837848463], [-118.32342361098931, 33.93226834279701], [-118.32342363937995, 33.93199353259484], [-118.32324562285159, 33.9319935682853], [-118.32324559387409, 33.93226837848463]]], 'c': [[[-118.32324890957211, 33.93184556158208], [-118.3234269582204, 33.93184538840734], [-118.32342698585838, 33.93157038586899], [-118.3232489701277, 33.93157039409077], [-118.32324890957211, 33.93184556158208]]], 'b': [[[-118.32446501281852, 33.93382830093175], [-118.32469465178349, 33.93401371331442], [-118.32482557842454, 33.93373671094244], [-118.32474968210079, 33.93370991710266], [-118.32467552482764, 33.93367993107341], [-118.32466512037963, 33.933676378206975], [-118.32465414487001, 33.93367433817557], [-118.32464291376506, 33.93367386852467], [-118.32463175060649, 33.93367498384334], [-118.32462097051506, 33.93367765237381], [-118.32461088431133, 33.93368179600033], [-118.32460178205915, 33.93368729716291], [-118.32459392070339, 33.93369399889028], [-118.32455440864135, 33.93374102222696], [-118.32451138120163, 33.93378584983995], [-118.32446501281852, 33.93382830093175]], [[-118.32412984318755, 33.93435821020326], [-118.32437441349586, 33.93454273141694], [-118.32440105567053, 33.93452159280172], [-118.32443169475404, 33.934504630474365], [-118.32445955431271, 33.93449406600224], [-118.32448905620996, 33.93448727538539], [-118.32441810925944, 33.93420548344047], [-118.32432181228724, 33.9342564937501], [-118.32412984318755, 33.93435821020326]]], 'd': [[[-118.32342361098931, 33.93226834279701], [-118.32360162810437, 33.932268306846666], [-118.3236016889799, 33.93199352403147], [-118.32342363937995, 33.93199353259484], [-118.32342361098931, 33.93226834279701]], [[-118.32360162810437, 33.932268306846666], [-118.32380275457592, 33.93226829127437], [-118.32380277598143, 33.93203469847962], [-118.32380201485829, 33.93202754070936], [-118.32379977729416, 33.932020603278595], [-118.32379613001628, 33.93201409209574], [-118.32379118093908, 33.93200820780694], [-118.32378508527886, 33.93200312860577], [-118.32377802287661, 33.93199900685896], [-118.3237702126206, 33.93199596906808], [-118.32376188562849, 33.931994107354164], [-118.32375329965659, 33.931993475984505], [-118.3236016889799, 33.93199352403147], [-118.32360162810437, 33.932268306846666]], [[-118.32469465178349, 33.93401371331442], [-118.32483195944481, 33.934124577119434], [-118.32490611928701, 33.934052440048426], [-118.32499369140133, 33.93378327519904], [-118.32490886353473, 33.933761925518134], [-118.32482557842454, 33.93373671094244], [-118.32469465178349, 33.93401371331442]]], 'e': [[[-118.32402541942062, 33.93425984266455], [-118.32402502490311, 33.93441374951826], [-118.32412984318755, 33.93435821020326], [-118.32432181228724, 33.9342564937501], [-118.3241717410122, 33.93400761270062], [-118.32409991718612, 33.934034974090316], [-118.3240258921391, 33.93405790358625], [-118.32402541942062, 33.93425984266455]]], 'f': [[[-118.32432759748971, 33.93392808543245], [-118.32452286119333, 33.93414997143693], [-118.32467452661973, 33.93413750193519], [-118.32483195944481, 33.934124577119434], [-118.32469465178349, 33.93401371331442], [-118.32446501281852, 33.93382830093175], [-118.32439883237907, 33.93388060967185], [-118.32432759748971, 33.93392808543245]]]}

patches = []

colorS = mcolors.CSS4_COLORS
colorkey = list(colorS.keys())

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

keyS = list(dictionary.keys())

for j in range(len(dictionary)):
    key = keyS[j]
    key_polygons = dictionary[key]
    for k, item in enumerate(key_polygons):
        polygon = Polygon(item, closed=True)
        patches.append(polygon)
    collection = PatchCollection(patches)
    collection.set_facecolor(colorkey[j])
    ax.add_collection(collection)
    
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Should the polygons with similar keys e.g. `a` have same color? If so, the dictionary can't have more than one instance of a key in it - only the latest key-value mapping will be stored in memory.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Yes, I am looking for the polygons with similar keys to have the same color. I was able to reorganize the dictionary to get all of the polygons under the same key, but it still has the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You create your dictionary with duplicate keys, which probably isn't what you intend to do.

It's a little unclear what you're exactly trying to do. You keep appending to a single list (`patches`), causing every `PatchCollection` to contain incrementally more polygons, until the last one that contains all, and then gets plotted with a single color (on top of all previous).

Also, do you consider a single item in the dictionary to be a single polygon? Or are those lists of polygons. For the former you probably should use a `PathCollection` instead, since that allows more complexity like inner-rings (holes) etc.

The `PatchCollection` has keywords (inherited from `Collection`) that you can use to directly set properties like the facecolors. A single color will just "broadcast" to all Polygons in the collection. Sometimes it's convenient to not set the colors immediately, but instead set the `array` keyword with a value (attribute). That value can than be mapped to a color using a colormap en normalizer.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

colors = mcolors.CSS4_COLORS
color_keys = list(colors.keys())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor="w")

for j, (key, polys) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
    
    coll = PatchCollection(
        [Polygon(p, closed=True) for p in polys],
        facecolors=color_keys[j],
    )
    ax.add_collection(coll)
    
ax.autoscale_view()
```

[image]

Coloring based on a value/attribute can be done with the example below. For discrete coloring like this (using the enumerate value) it doesn't add much, but it becomes useful when you for example want to color the polygon based on a continuous value.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor="w")

cmap = mpl.colormaps["Spectral"].copy()
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,  vmax=len(dictionary))

for j, (key, polys) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
    
    coll = PatchCollection(
        [Polygon(p, closed=True) for p in polys],
        array=[j], cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
    )
    ax.add_collection(coll)
    
ax.autoscale_view()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the dictionary, that was how it was when it was brought in, I have edited it to have all the polygons under their specific key.

Thank you for the detailed explanation! That was very useful in better understanding patches and collections.
However, your comment about appending to a single list was what fixed it for me! I was meaning to create a list of patches, add a color to them and then plot them and then reset that list. So I moved the _patches = []_ right under the _for j_ line. Probably not the most elegant but it is working!